# SQL Azure Database Named Pipes Error

Tags: sql, iis-7, azure-sql-database

Up until last night, my site (hosted by DiscountASP.net) and the SQL Azure database that it connects to were running normally.

For some reason, during the night, the site went down with a named pipe error. Error 40.

Having prefixed the server name with "tcp:" in the connection string, the error is now:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)
```

So, just to be clear, the web.config file did not change at all between the time the website last worked and the item the named pipe error came up.

Now, the username, password and instance name are all correct since the site runs locally against the remote SQl Azure server perfectly.

I've checked the instance name and the SQl Azure access rules, ensuring that the web server's IP address is whitelisted.

Any ideas on whats wrong?

Comment: Logged in to the Windows Azure portal to try and manage the database. Can't manage it. Still works locally against the remote server though.

Comment: Was there a resolution to this? I'm experiencing an identical issue except that my site is hosted on an Amazon instance and using SQL Azure for the database. It's literally stopped working from one day to the next even though my connection string has been unchanged for the more than 1 year. I just don't know why it would stop from one day to the next like this. PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this right, your local website (on-premise) can connect to SQL Azure, but your website deployed in Azure can't?

Make sure your firewall rules has the "allow other windows azure services to access this server".  Checking this option off basically prevents any azure-hosted application/service from connecting to your database.

Comment: Half right... the website is not on azure, just the database.

Comment: Ah - I now see that your site is hosted by DiscountASP.net.  Did you check that the IP of your website did not change? Did you check the firewall settings?

Comment: Yes checked that. However, if an IP address is not on the white list, SQl Azure returns an explicit error message that tells you the IP address and where to add it. My error is way before that in the process - the server can't even open a connection.

Comment: Was there a resolution to this? I'm experiencing an identical issue except that my site is hosted on an Amazon instance and using SQL Azure for the database. It's literally stopped working from one day to the next even though my connection string has been unchanged for the more than 1 year. I just don't know why it would stop from one day to the next like this. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: The resolution, if you can call it that, was to move the DB to Discountasp.net servers so that any calls wouldn't have to traverse firewalls. Not much of a solution - but it resolved the issue and the site got back up and running. As far as solving the error - I never did figure it out. Sorry I can't be of more help.